# Less like middleware for javascript files

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I would like to have something like less but for javascript files. I know that `grunt-contrib-concat` do that thing, making .map file from many .js files. I don't want to use `grunt` to success that task. Do you know any other package? I have searched others without success.

Comment: Like [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/)?

Comment: no, like grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: On functionalities more like less middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack or SystemJS would be my recommendation. Both will actually build your javascript, resolving dependencies and allowing you to use es6 or commonjs module loading. This is a more modern and preferred approach to simply concatenating files.

Comment: Webpack looks nice, i will test it now

Comment: It's more complex then it should be :)

Comment: It's not all that complex once you get the hang of it and it gives you way more power than simple concatenation.